# I get all values from database by sql

Tags: php, database, laravel

So, I have a table `countries` with a column `flag.`Here I have codes for every country by id.I tried to join the table in my page by SQL query, but I've got this...And I need to display only the right flag, by the id of country, not all the flags.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOtvf.jpg

My database structure : table `countries` , column `id`, `country` and `flag`

Here is my code :

*Controller:*

```
             $data['contact_users'] = DB::table('contacts')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
                ->join('industries', 'industries.id', '=', 'users.industry_id')
                ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
                ->join('organization_types', 'organization_types.id', '=', 'users.organization_type_id')
                ->join("role_users", "role_users.user_id","=","users.id")
                ->leftJoin("career_paths", "career_paths.user_id","=","users.id")
                ->select('users.*', 'industries.industry', 'countries.country', 'organization_types.organization_type', "role_users.role_id", 'career_paths.function_id')
                ->where('contacts.contact_id', '!=', $id)
                ->where('users.deleted_at', '=', null)
                ->whereIn('contacts.user_id', $contact_id)
                ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $contact_id)
                ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $inviter_id)
                ->groupBy('contact_id')
                ->take(4)
                ->get();      

                $flags = DB::select('SELECT flag FROM countries WHERE country = "India"');
```

*View:*

```
@foreach ($flags as $flag)
{{ $contact->country }} <span class="{{ $flag->flag}}"></span>
@endforeach</a><br>
```

With `{{ $contact->country }}` I get the name of country and with `{{ $contact->id }}` I get the id of country.How can I make a conection between id and flag column?

Comment: So you need to add a WHERE clause to you query.

Comment: yes, but I don't know exactly how to do that.I've tried many possibilities but doesn't seems to works.It's the first time for me when I'm using the SQL query.

Comment: Do you have access to the ID of the country you want to get the flag of?

Comment: Yes, by `$country->id`

Comment: This [does not seem very complicated](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: "SELECT flag FROM countries WHERE country = 'India'"

Comment: I have different countries of users, not only India.

Comment: With ` $flags = DB::table('countries')
                ->whereColumn('flag', '=', 'id')
                ->get();` I didn't get anything.

Comment: are you trying to display single record for a country and corresponding flag? or you want to display all the country alongside their flags?

Comment: Only one record for a country and corresponding flag.For example : I have 4 users on my site, and every has a country by `$country->country` or `$country->id`.

Comment: do u have flag table?

Comment: I have flag column in `countries` table, where I also have `id` and `country`

Comment: @AndreiNagy try $contact->flag .

Comment: @AndreiNagy connection between id and flag? What do you mean?

Comment: okay. good. it seems to me you dont have a table call flag?

Comment: With $contact->flag I got : Undefined property: stdClass::$flag . I mean that Id 1 is United States, which has a code for the flag.I need to associate the correct flag by every id, like in my database.

Comment: No, I only have a column for flag, like here : SELECT flag FROM countries @JuliusFasema

Comment: let me help you out here. sending the code right away!

Comment: $flags = DB::table('country')->get();

Comment: If you select only flag from countries table, how you getting the value of id?

Comment: @farooq , I have another query before...for contact, here is how I pick the id of country associated by user: `->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')`

Comment: @JuliusFasema I just posted the above query.

Comment: Maybe is easly to join the flag in that query? And use $contact->flag on my site?

Comment: okay! seen the updated question. see my sample code below. i created a table where all the flags are stored. then in country table i defined the flagid column where flag will relate to the country via the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// try this. you should have two tables here since you mentioned something like joining two tables. sample data and query.

```
countries: id | country | flagid
           ---|---------|----
            1 |  US     |  1

flag: id | flag
      ----------
       1 |  image
```

//controller. this code is assume you are selecting/inputing the country name

```
public function getSingleFlag(Request $request)
{
  $country = $request->input('countryname')

  $data['country']=DB::table('countries')
  ->leftjoin('flag','countries.flagid','=','flag.id')
  ->where('country',$country)
  ->first();

   return view('form',$data)
}
```

//this code is assume you are not selecting/inputing the country name. you just want to display all the countries with corresponding flags

```
public function getAllFlag()
{
  $data['country']=DB::table('countries')
  ->leftjoin('flag','countries.flagid','=','flag.id')
  ->get();

   return view('form',$data)
}


//your blade.
//for the first function
<p> {{ $country->country }} - {{ $country->flag}}</p>  


//for the second function use foreach

@foreach($country as $c)

   <p> {{ $c->country }} - {{ $c->flag}}</p>

@endforeach
```

note: remember to use your image tag to display your flag. just giving you an insight how it will be achieved

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So...it's possible to adapt this code for a structure like that ? countries: id | country | flag
           ---|---------|----
            1 |  US     |  flag-icon flag-icon-us ? I'm using flag icon css, I dont have the images saved in my database.

Comment: yes. thats good. using either fa fa-icon  would even make the whole thing alot easier.

Comment: The problem is..This thing working on many many pages, only in one doesn't working.Can I make this code adapted on my table? Because I have id - country -flag ( where I have my code for icon).Can I make a code like ->leftjoin('flag','countries.flag','=','countries.id')?

Comment: Or maybe can I join to my Query, above the $flags, column flag from countries?  Maybe here? ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')

Comment: i think this will go. ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id') . since you identified each user by the country id

Comment: Yes, by this join I identified the users by country id. And maybe now should I identify the country id with country flag?

Comment: This isn't works:( because I already have an join for countries :( here ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')

Comment: then you need flag table. duplicate the country table renamed the duplicate as flag. delete every necessary column leaving id, flag. create your join and set your conditions